# Angular and FileMaker API

Tags: angular, rest, api, filemaker

I'm trying to connect to FileMaker Server 17 using its own API through my Angular application. I'm using a proxy because of CORS issue.

I think I'm doing everything correctly but for some reason I can't get it work. I get an error 10

> code: "10"
>
> message: "HTTP Authorization header or OAuth headers are missing."

Here is my connection service:

```
connectToAPI() {
        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
             'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             Authorization: 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
            })};
        const proxyurl = 'https://bypasscors.herokuapp.com/api/?url=';
        const server = 'https://myserver.com/fmi/data/v1/databases/database';
        return this.http.post(proxyurl + encodeURIComponent(server + '/sessions'), {body: '', httpOptions}
        ).subscribe(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }
```

On the **proxy** api it tells me to pass the headers as part of the body, on which I did. I also tried passing the header on the options part of the http post request and nothing.

*BTW, this is to get the authorization token*.

Comment: it may be the format you're sending the headers in.  Does the proxy api give you more detail about what format you need to pass them through the request body? Because right now you are sending 2 values in the body, the first value is an empty string, the second value is an object with 2 keys.

Comment: Yes! The proxy API says to pass the header inside the body. I tried inside, outside and nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

Body should be empty curly braces for this endpoint {}
Did you try that?

Comment: Hey! I did, nothing :/

Comment: You can try to get token using postman and pass here for a request that accepts token. If still same error, the header send method for proxy might be the issue.